# Substitution of expressions for the output

Tags: replacement, symbolic, built-in-symbols

I have a code which gives this kind of output :

```
W = Sum[v[j]*b[j], {j, 1, 3}];
AA = (v[1]*b[1] + v[2]*b[2] + v[3]*b[3])*2 + 3 ;
```

I know that if i want to substitute, for example, v[1] with 2 I have to do:

```
AA = (v[1]*b[1] + v[2]*b[2] + v[3]*b[3])*2 + 3  /. v[1] -> 2
```

But if i want to substitute the expression of `W` how should i do? Because if i do this:

```
    W = Sum[v[j]*b[j], {j, 1, 3}];
AA = (v[1]*b[1] + v[2]*b[2] + v[3]*b[3])*2 + 3  /. 
  W -> (b[1] v[1] + b[2] v[2] + b[3] v[3])
```

I unfortunately obtain:

```
3 + 2 (b[1] v[1] + b[2] v[2] + b[3] v[3])
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
Simplify[AA, W == ww]
```

> 3 + 2 ww